# unable to install MYSQLDB

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-4dq45q4u/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
neosoft@neosoft:~$ ^C
```

Comment: Welcome in StackOverflow! Sorry but can I ask you if you can improve a bit your question to be more readable? Now it's a wall of text. It's difficult to help you in this case. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try `sudo pip3 install ...`

Comment: sudo pip install  ConfigParser

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

That module was renamed `configparser`in Python 3. So it appears you are trying to install the Python 2 version of `mysql` in a Python 3 environment.